# C#: Verify signature does not work, but works with Java

Tags: java, c#, rsa, signature

I have a problem verifying an RSA signature with C# by providing digest only. Here is my code in Java, which returns a "true" value, indicating that the signature is correct:

```
        String certificateBase64 = "MIIC6jCCAdKgAwI...";
        String signatureValueBase64 = "d0rLeNX+sQCZ3io0ji6j0P2M4bpGYxA+WKS6KkP4GYDxm4qrfhnvrKUOqvDmXNT3kNhv8I6Se6T4TFqJmYPTTQ8O914nDNmqASlknii6EA4ALExVhXfuZ7BeVNZy33AacBF8K/GIYH9DyvtWz9lVFaIX4BV9176CHo2FdSYXfNnrpJWQBIlpEhnsVHThCAabF/AOM/G2vgr5yO2Etbz3VCyZJesBOEmqRl6VlndFXZBgR527zknrH5fnACYrDacVXnFFY1OYGhaRI7tZrOvgkELnXV55aYhShWjAVcrGxaTC6vCHx3Ou4bsbjSCs4PXNMaaPcHUKH99xXODHFnMOjA==";
        String hashBase64 = "MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIGlE+Lr0y76nMOdxNLu1k5g4l3feoWU4MYZm8yo0N5vE";

        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();

        CertificateFactory x509Factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        X509Certificate x509Cert;
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(decoder.decode(certificateBase64))) {
            x509Cert = (X509Certificate) x509Factory.generateCertificate(bais);
        }

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
        signature.initVerify(x509Cert.getPublicKey());
        signature.update(decoder.decode(hashBase64));

        boolean valid = signature.verify(decoder.decode(signatureValueBase64));
        System.out.println(valid);
```

However, when I try to validate signature with C# providing the same input parameters, I always receive "false". Here is my code:

```
    string certificateBase64 = "MIIC6jCCAdKgAwI...";
    string signatureValueBase64 = "d0rLeNX+sQCZ3io0ji6j0P2M4bpGYxA+WKS6KkP4GYDxm4qrfhnvrKUOqvDmXNT3kNhv8I6Se6T4TFqJmYPTTQ8O914nDNmqASlknii6EA4ALExVhXfuZ7BeVNZy33AacBF8K/GIYH9DyvtWz9lVFaIX4BV9176CHo2FdSYXfNnrpJWQBIlpEhnsVHThCAabF/AOM/G2vgr5yO2Etbz3VCyZJesBOEmqRl6VlndFXZBgR527zknrH5fnACYrDacVXnFFY1OYGhaRI7tZrOvgkELnXV55aYhShWjAVcrGxaTC6vCHx3Ou4bsbjSCs4PXNMaaPcHUKH99xXODHFnMOjA==";
    string hashBase64 = "MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIGlE+Lr0y76nMOdxNLu1k5g4l3feoWU4MYZm8yo0N5vE";

    byte[] certificateBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certificateBase64);
    byte[] signatureValueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureValueBase64);
    byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashBase64);

    X509Certificate2 x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes);
    RSA publicKey = (RSA)x509Cert.GetRSAPublicKey();

    bool isValid = publicKey.VerifyHash(hashBytes, signatureValueBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
        
    Console.WriteLine(isValid);
```

Do you have any ideas?

I tried to validate signature in C# using RSA, RSACryptoServiceProvider and RSAPKCS1Signatureformatter, but no luck with none of them.
I'm not experienced C# programmer, so I do not know all the possibilities.

Comment: `Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA")` <> SHA256..., that would be `"SHA256withRSA"`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - In the Java code, although `NONEwithRSA` is used, the *DigestInfo* value (consisting of SHA256-ID || SHA256-hash) is passed, which is equivalent to signing the data (from which the SHA256-hash was generated) with SHA256withRSA.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, "NONEwithRSA" indicates that the hash value is computed in advance, thus the Signature instance will no apply hash function on the provided data, but will try to verify it directly. The same applies on signing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java code uses PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. To find a fix for the C# code, at least a rough understanding of PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is required (for an exact specification see [RFC8017](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-9.2)):

For PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, the message M is first hashed: H, then the digest ID is prepended:
T = ID || H (more precisely, T is the DER encoding of the DigestInfo).
When padding, T is prefixed with 0x00 || 0x01 || PS || 0x00, where PS consists of so many 0xFF values that the signature size is equal to the RSA key size (i.e. the modulus).

So the whole signature is: 0x00 || 0x01 || PS || 0x00 || T.

---

In the Java code, `hashBase64` corresponds to the Base64 encoding of T, where the ID corresponds to that of SHA256. To see this, the easiest way is to Base64 decode `hashBase64` and then hex encode the resulting data:

```
3031300d060960864801650304020105000420 6944f8baf4cbbea730e77134bbb59398389777dea16538318666f32a34379bc4
```

This value, i.e. T, becomes most understandable when viewed in an Asn.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/.

`NONEwithRSA` defines that the data is *directly* interpreted as T (so neither the message is hashed nor an ID is prepended).

In this way, the signature 0x00 || 0x01 || PS || 0x00 || T is also generated, i.e. you get the same PKCS#1 v1.5 compliant signature as if you use the original data (from which the hash was generated) and the algorithm `SHA256withRSA`.

Signing already hashed data is the actual purpose of `NONEwithRSA` (namely when the signing authority is only allowed to know the hash, but not the actual data). Unfortunately, `NONEwithRSA` is often misused, that is, for signing *unhashed* data.

---

In the C# code the same can be achieved with `VerifyHash()`. However, not T must be passed, but only the hash. The digest ID is added *implicitly* by `VerifyHash()`, which is the reason that the digest must be specified.

The bug in the current C# code is that T (i.e. `hashBytes`) and not H is passed, so replace `hashBytes` with `hashBytes[^32..]` and verification is successful.

---

Sample code Java:

```java
// Import public key
byte[] spkiDer = Base64.getDecoder().decode("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");
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(spkiDer);
RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(keySpecX509);

// Verify
byte[] hashBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIGlE+Lr0y76nMOdxNLu1k5g4l3feoWU4MYZm8yo0N5vE");
byte[] signature = Base64.getDecoder().decode("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");
Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
verifier.initVerify(pubKey);
verifier.update(hashBytes);                     // pass T = ID|H
boolean verified = verifier.verify(signature);
System.out.println(verified);                   // true
```

Sample code C#:

```cs
// Import public key
byte[] spkiDer = Convert.FromBase64String("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");
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(spkiDer, out _);

// Verify
byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIGlE+Lr0y76nMOdxNLu1k5g4l3feoWU4MYZm8yo0N5vE");
byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String("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");
bool verified = rsa.VerifyHash(
    hashBytes[^32..],               // pass H
    signature,
    HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,       // digest is explicitly specified
    RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
Console.WriteLine(verified);        // True
```

Comment: You are the man! Did not know about different hash interpretation in C# (as I actually do not work with this language). Your code sample works perfectly!